# Representing LXC component configuration in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I want to represent components of LXC in django; so I defined them in models: Container, Network, Profile and Devices where each one of them have a set of attributs, but when it comes to representing configuration (each component has a set of configuration fields), I don't know if it is the right approach to follow. Below is an example code, given the fact that I use MongoDB as a database engine.

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    remote = models.CharField()
    architecture = models.CharField()
    creation = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField()
    containerType = models.CharField()
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    config = EmbeddedModelField('ContainerConfig')


class ContainerConfig(models.Model):
    bootAutostart = models.BooleanField()
    bootAutoStartDelay = models.IntegerField()
    bootAutostartPriority = models.IntegerField()
    bootHostShutDownTimeOut = models.IntegerField()
    bootStopPrority = models.IntegerField()
    env = models.CharField()
    limitsCpu = models.CharField()
    limitsCpuAllowance = models.CharField()
    limitsCpuPriority = models.CharField()
    limitsDiskPriority = models.IntegerField()
    limitsHugePages64K = models.CharField()
```

Is it right to follow this approach?